# How can I create a Realm database with initial data for my android app?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to create a database for my android application using Realm. I need to have data that is pre-populated when the app is installed. Setting a Realm Migration as part of the RealmConfiguration does not run when the version of the database is 0 (defaults to 0 initially). How can I add data the first time the application is setup?

Answer (score 10):

Realm Java 0.89 introduced a method that allows for specifying a transaction to be run when a Realm database is created for the first time. This method, [`RealmConfiguration.Builder.initialData(Realm.Transaction transaction)`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#initialData-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-), is called as part of setting up the RealmConfiguration Builder.

For example

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .name("myrealm.realm")
  .initialData(new MyInitialDataRealmTransaction()), 
  .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing right now that works is to check if this is the first time my app is installed and create a new object.

```
if (Preferences.freshInstall(getApplicationContext())) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Category inbox = new Category("Inbox", "#445566");
        realm.copyToRealm(inbox);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        Preferences.notNew(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

There should be a better way to do this using Realm Migrations

Comment: Migrations are not meant for pre populating the database. Keeping track of  a boolean in preferences ins probably the easiest to do if you don't want to ship a pre populated file with the app. That said adding some way of providing data the first time a Realm is created sounds like a use case we could support better.

Answer (score 0):

The initial data transaction setup, as shown by [@Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850404/267680) in Realm Java *works*! I only wish that it was present in Realm Cocoa, as well.

I've created an issue for this, in the Github tracker [here, #3877](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3877).