# How to seed a Realm database with standard data?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm working on a basic project for fitness tracking. I want to initialize the app with an exercise library prepared for the user. How do you provide the data and set up the transaction to populate the database? I've seen the answer below, but I can't find how to actually set up the example, defined in the answer as `MyInitialDataRealmTransaction`.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

[How can I create a Realm database with initial data for my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304125/how-can-i-create-a-realm-database-with-initial-data-for-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

The initial data takes a transaction as a parameter which runs if the Realm was first created or the Realm was deleted because migration was needed and the config for that was set.

Here is a basic example.

```
public class RealmInitialData implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(1);
        book.setAuthor("Reto Meier");
        book.setTitle("Android 4 Application Development");
        book.setImageUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/images/realm/1.png");
        realm.insertOrUpdate(book);

        book.setId(2);
        book.setAuthor("Itzik Ben-Gan");
        book.setTitle("Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals");
        book.setImageUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/images/realm/2.png");
        realm.insertOrUpdate(book);

        book.setId(3);
        book.setAuthor("Magnus Lie Hetland");
        book.setTitle("Beginning Python: From Novice To Professional Paperback");
        book.setImageUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/images/realm/3.png");
        realm.insertOrUpdate(book);

        book.setId(4);
        book.setAuthor("Chad Fowler");
        book.setTitle("The Passionate Programmer: Creating a Remarkable Career in Software Development");
        book.setImageUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/images/realm/4.png");
        realm.insertOrUpdate(book);

        book.setId(5);
        book.setAuthor("Yashavant Kanetkar");
        book.setTitle("Written Test Questions In C Programming");
        book.setImageUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/images/realm/5.png");
        realm.insertOrUpdate(book);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return RealmInitialData.class.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof RealmInitialData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For my use case, I have a large managed data set for the exercises - let's say 100. It doesn't seem like a practical approach to create 100 definitions of objects to save. It seems like maybe I'd want to do something similar to what you've suggested in the `execute` method and figure out how to read the data from a CSV or similar?

Comment: I revised the code a bit to show how to use only 1 unmanaged object to save N objects

Comment: I put together a solution I like using JSON which allows you to also maintain the data beyond the first instantiation. I'll post the approach.

Comment: @justinraczak can you please post your approach?

Comment: @Japharr I simply created a JSON file with my structured data and used Realm's `createOrUpdateAllFromJson` functionality. The transaction is performed fresh every time the app is loaded.

Comment: How does this run automatically on Realm creation or migration?

Comment: Implementing Realm.Trasaction throws me an Error, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score -3):

Check out [this](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) java library for generating fake data. It's well organized and it also saves a lot of time.